# Hamiltonian of a simple graph

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter

I have a spin system:
[image]

As shown in the picture, there are two spins S1 and S2, and a pair of interactions between them. One is a ferromagnetic interaction and the other is anti ferromagnetic interaction. I am trying to calculate the Hamiltonian of this system.

The Hamiltonian of the system is:

$$ H = -J_F S1_z  S2_z    +J_{AF} S1_z  S2_z  $$

$S1_z$ is the spin matrix for Z direction for spin 1 and $S2_z$ is the spin matrix for Z direction for spin 2. If we allow two random values for $J_F$ and $J_{AF}$, -0.5 and 0.5 respectively the Hamiltonian of the system is as follows.

$$ H = 0.5 S1_z  S2_z    + 0.5 S1_z  S2_z  $$
$$  = S1_z  S2_z  $$
$$ =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & -1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$ =
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

Am I able to calculate the Hamiltonian correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hamiltonian of this system lives in a 4-dimensional Hilbert space since you have two spin $1/2$. Therefore, you should represent the spin matrix in this four dimensional space like this:

$S_1^z=\begin{pmatrix}
-0.5 & 0 &0  &0 \\ 
 0&-0.5  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0.5  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &0.5 
\end{pmatrix}$ , $S_2^z=\begin{pmatrix}
-0.5 & 0 &0  &0 \\ 
 0&0.5  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &-0.5  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &0.5 
\end{pmatrix}$

The order of the four states along the rows and columns is $|DD\rangle,|DU\rangle, |UD\rangle, |UU\rangle$ where $U$ stands for spin up and $D$ stands for spin down.

In this case $S_1^z.S_2^z=\begin{pmatrix}
0.25 & 0 &0  &0 \\ 
 0&-0.25  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &-0.25  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &0.25 
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I am little bit confused here. Let me define a single bit $\frac{1}{2}$ spin as $ |Z\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ or logic zero and a single bit $-\frac{1}{2}$ spin as $ |O\rangle =  \begin{pmatrix}  
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ or logic one. (contd...)

Comment: So, for a two spin spin system, the state vectors are $|ZZ\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$, $|ZO\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$, $|OZ\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$ and $|OO\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$. To know the spins I operate your operators on the state vectors.

Comment: When I operate $S_1^z$  on $|ZZ\rangle$ I get the following result. 
$$
S_1^z . |ZZ\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
        -0.5 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & -0.5 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0.5 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0.5 \\
        \end{pmatrix} . \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
        -0.5 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ I don't understand what to make of it. But when I calculate the expected value, i.e., $\langle ZZ | S_1^z | ZZ \rangle$ (contd...)

Comment: I get $\begin{pmatrix}
        -0.5 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$. I am not sure if the expectation value I am getting is the $-\frac{1}{1}$-spin. If so, I think I almost understand you. But in page 7 of web.uconn.edu/~ch351vc/pdfs/spin1.pdf, the operator is different. It is $\Sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & -2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}. $ Any clue?

Comment: Moreover, If I operate $ \Sigma_z = \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ on |ZZ\rangle I get $\begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\
        0 \\ \end{pmatrix}$ and if I use $\Sigma_z$ as an observable the expected value is $\begin{pmatrix}
        2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Moreover the expected values of $S_1^z . S_2^z$ is 0.25 for $|ZZ\rangle$ or $|OO\rangle$ and -0.25 for the rest two. But, the expected values of $\Sigma_z$ is 0 when two spins are opposite and non-zero when they are same. I think $\Sigma_z$ gives us information about interaction.

Comment: $\Sigma_z=S_1^z+S_2^z$ The first matrix you wrote for $\Sigma_z$ is consistent with the definitions for$S_1^z$ and $S_2^z$. What is the problem in $S_1^z |ZZ\rangle=-0.5|ZZ\rangle$ ? Isn't this expected?